# Highlight search term in textblock 

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, textblock

I have a search textbox on silverlight app where user types in search term and results are displayed in textblock, requirement is the search term matches should be highlighted in textblocks.

I have seen some examples of highlighting search terms in textblock but none using mvvm pattern. Im binding text property of textblock in viewmodel, i tried to access inline collection to specify different  tags but later came to know that inline collection is not bindable.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

This description is being set in ViewModel

Comment: Could you describe non-MVVM solution?

Comment: MVVM means the VM is concerned with the business and the View is concerned with the display.  You can feel free to handle this in the codebehind of the view, or by creating a UserControl to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i figured out how to do it in MVVM.

1. I used a `RadRichTextBox` control from Telerik to achieve the task.
2. I created a new class with dependency property as `bindableXaml` & method which converts string to XAML(created new `RadRichTextBox` in code to do highlight work in this and returned result as `radDocument`)
3. Attached it to `RadRichTextBox`, so in `ViewModel` the string from DB is converted into desired XAML format via `StringToXaml` method. You can achieve the same result using `RichTextBox` but the XAML created in it will require `StringBuilder` and `RegEx.Match()` to do highlight work.

Answer (score 2):

As Will mentioned, this is View functionality, so putting it in the Views code behind is acceptable.

in your .xaml.cs

```
private void ButtonSearchRequest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Search(TextBoxToSearch, TextBoxSearchTerm.Text);
}

private void Search(TextBox tb, string strSearchTerm)
{
    strSearchTerm = strSearchTerm.Trim().ToLower();
    int iNextMatch = tb.Text.ToLower().IndexOf(strSearchTerm);

    if (iNextMatch >= 0)
    {
        tb.Focus();
        tb.CaretIndex = iNextMatch;
        tb.Select(iNextMatch, strSearchTerm.Length);
        tb.ScrollToLine(tb.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(iNextMatch));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks guys...but code behind will never pass code review in my organisation.I need a way to generate the inline collection dynamically and bind it to textblock with desired formatting of text.I can also consider solutions with Richtextbox.